# Maven SAR packaging: how to change package structure?

Tags: maven, build, jboss, pom.xml, sar

I've been trying to get Maven to package up a SAR and have been using the maven jboss packaging plugin with the jboss-sar packaging type.

By default, the plugin seems to package the class directory (from src/main/java) into the root of the SAR (com/../etc). For my purposes I need it to live in WEB-INF/classes/com/.../etc but i've had no luck in convincing the plugin to alter the class packaging directory.

I've resorted to using the maven assembly plugin to alter the the layout using an assembly descriptor but this seems a bit like overkill, and it also means that two SARs get generated (one with the standard format and one with the assembly-modified format, which is undesirable).

I'm pretty new to maven and have spent a lot of time trying to find a neat way around this issue but have so far only come up with overly complicated solutions to what is basically a simple problem.

(Please note that conforming to this archive structure is out of my hands and deviating from it isn't a viable option)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

That sounds you need the [war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) which packages a war which has the WEB-INF/classes folder etc. 
Furthermore you have to change the packaging of your project to "war" instead of "jar" or "sar" in your case.

Comment: That's actually what I was using to solve the problem initially though it really ought to be a SAR - I realise this might be breaking some conventions. It has (what I believe to be) SAR-specific descriptors, hence why i'm trying to no longer package it as a WAR.